# how to compare email in where clause using prisma orm in node js?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, prisma

I don't understand how to use the "where" clause in Prisma ORM. I want to compare with the email inside the "where" clause but it is saying that you can't compare with anything other than the "id"

```
export const verifyUser = async (payload) => {
  return await prisma.user.update({
    where: {
     
        email: payload.id,
      
    },
    data: {
      active: true,
    },
  });
};
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f38dR.png)

Comment: Can you please provide details about the payload?  It looks like you are comparing the email with the payload.id instead you should compare payload.email. like this in where condition. email: payload.id,

Comment: Can you share your schema and also try enabling the feature to filter on [non-unique fields](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-on-non-unique-fields-with-userwhereuniqueinput)? This is assuming email is not unique in your schema